# Change fill factor for specific indexes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 which is undergoing a tuning process, and the script we used to check what was impacting its performance reported that many indexes of this database had the wrong fill factor. What I mean by that is, tables that are used only for consulting values and have very few rows have their indexes set with fill factor as 80, and I want to change them to 99.

This is the message I got from the script that checked the database:

> Self Loathing Indexes: Low Fill Factor: clustered index

So, I already have the list of indexes I need to change, and I know the process of changing such thing in an index, which is to drop it and create it again.
What I need is a script which will get the indexes names from an "In" clause and change all their fill factors to 99, is that possible?

Comment: Why 99?  Why drop and recreate?  If it is FK then that is a problem.  A table with very few rows and fill factor of 80 should not be giving you performance problems.

Comment: Well, as i said we have tables that have very few rolls, like 10 or so, and these tables never get updated, they are just there for reference, so 99 would be a good value for it, in my vision, do you have another point of view about it?
To modify an index we have to drop it and recreate it right? This database does not have any foreign key.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by getting names from an "in" clause...what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Do you have any evidence the small tables with a fill factor of 80 are giving you any performance problems?  No they are not.  An 80 fill on a small table is not wasting but very small disk space.  With only 10 rows TSQL is probably doing a full scan anyway.  You are tying to fix a problem that is not really a problem.

Comment: If you're sure you want to do it, I'd just use SQL to construct my SQL statements, then copy them to another query window, and execute them there.  No need to fully automate it and wrap it in a stored proc for a one time change.

Comment: I hate to admit this, but I do this using a WHILE loop and build dynamic SQL for all my `ALTER INDEX` statements.